# User.Identity is null in any Function (MVC 4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

```
  public List<SelectListItem> AddressTitleList()
        {
            string ID = User.Identity.Name;
            List<SelectListItem> title = new List<SelectListItem>();
            using (LYCHEEntities DB = new LYCHEEntities())
            {
                int ID = Convert.ToInt16(User.Identity.Name.ToString());

                var titles = from g in DB.UserAddresses
                             where g.UserID == ID
                             select new { g.Title, g.UserAddressID };

                foreach (var q in titles)
                {
                    title.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = q.Title, Value = q.UserAddressID.ToString() });
                }

            }
            return title;
        }
```

I am getting User.Identity.Name in any **ActionResult** but not in above function, why? is there any alternative to this? Why i am getting User = Null. Kindly Help :)

Note: Above function/method is not an **ActionResult** and i have only one controller.

I don't know it will help or not but HttpContext is also null in above function ... also i am calling this function from the View

```
 @{ LYCHE.Controllers.HomeController c = new LYCHE.Controllers.HomeController();

            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.myTitle,c.AddressTitleList(), new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.myTitle)
```

Comment: Please describe more context. Can you get User.Identity.Name in another ActionResult of the same controller class with above function? Or where did you put above function

Comment: I have only one controller so, yes, it is in the same controller. and Yes i can get it in any ActionResult of the same controller.

Comment: have u add the [Authorize]  attribute for the method ?

Comment: It will not fix the problem ... @LittleDragon

Comment: That is because you are instantiating the controller yourself `var c = new HomeController()`.  Instead, create an overload function `AddressTitleList(int userId)` and pass `User.Identity.Name` to that function from your view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using System.Web.Security class, kindly ensure you initialized membership by adding below on class

[InitializeSimpleMembership]

example:

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class MyController : Controller
{
  // here is my class code 
 }
```

Comment: U mean i should add [InitializeSimpleMembership] above the function? or Controller Class? `[InitializeSimpleMembership] public List<SelectListItem> AddressTitleList()`

Comment: above the controller class dear, you can refer the example also.